# PDF and Graph using C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I am developing windows service in .net using c# language. The service have to generate report in PDF format. The report should have graph in it. I like to know how can we create PDF file and add graph in it.

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)., which is an open source project. It supports charting, maybe it supports also the features you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to spend some buck, I would suggest going in for ABCPDF.Net from [websupergoo](http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm#pd). There are lots of examples included and the API is easy to use.

For charting, if you are open to using .Net 3.5, look at the [System.Web.DataVisualization](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displaylang=en) namespace. It offers all the features of Dundas Charts Professional edition.
You may also want to take a look at [zedgraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

i have used this commercial [websupergoo](http://websupergoo.com/) API for PDF generation and it was super simple to work upon. worth every penny spent.

For graphs you can implement any of the following controls :

- [free & open source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/webchart.aspx)
- [dotnetcharting](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/)
- [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Best is you can use crystal Report, create graph on Crystal report and then export it to pdf

Answer (score 0):

I've been pretty happy using the Stimulsoft reporting engine. Supports Graphs and PDF output.

Answer (score 0):

For charting purposes, I came across the [FF Chartwell font](https://www.fontfont.com/how-to-use-ff-chartwell) this week, seems like a great idea.. Might do what you want from a chart perspective, although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fastest way is to create report in html and then convert it to pdf.
You can use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) or [jsreport](http://jsreport.net) to convert html to pdf including all your charts. Charts can be done for example using [jquery flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/). This is possible because both mentioned technologies are also interpreting javascript.

Look at my post [pdf reports in c#](http://jsreport.net/blog/pdf-reports-in-csharp) or more specifically at the post [charts in pdf reports](http://jsreport.net/blog/charts-in-pdf-reports).

Disclaimer: I am the author of jsreport

Comment: I am facing the same question, I also thought about transforming html to pdf, but the problem wkhtmltopdf fails alot of the times to render my html page..